# How companies bill for their services?

Tags: accounting, billing

I'm doing an accounting software as part of a homework project, targetting SMB to print delivery forms and invoices for physical products and services (services such as laundry).

But I don't know when companies bill (print and send invoices) their customers for services; do they bill by monthly usage or by the start of the next month? What are the other methods of billing?

Comment: This question is pretty broad. It is going to vary a lot by local business customs, the industry, contract type, and industry. can you be more specific in your question about what the problem is you are trying to solve in your software?

Comment: @JohnFx What about the last edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's "monthly" for some services, and "as needed" for other services.

As far as "when", monthly billing for a large number of customers typically happens all during the month, to spread out the processing load.  Others are based on when during the month that the customer became a customer.

Comment: What's meant by "as needed" - Could you explain further?

Comment: "*What's meant by "as needed" - Could you explain further?*"  If I didn't need your services, then you didn't provide me service.  Thus, you don't need to bill me.